# ubuntu guest on RHEL kvm *(x86_64) is failing

Tags: kvm

I have a x86_64 m/c and i successfully installed Sles12 and RHEL7 guests on this m/c. But while creating a ubuntu guest (64 bit), this is failing.

```
virt-install --name=ubuntu1 --virt-type=kvm --boot cdrom,hd --network=default,model=virtio --disk /dev/dm-13,size=300,format=raw,bus=virtio,cache=none,sparse=true --memory=8192 --vcpu=2 --location=/home/suse/ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso  --console pty,target_type=serial --graphics none --extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
Starting install...
Retrieving file info...                                                      |  134 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file version.info...                                                                                                                           |116 B  00:00:00
ERROR    Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree.

lsmod|grep kvm
    kvm_intel             162153  8
    kvm                   525259  1 kvm_intel
```

While running with debug, this is expecting i386 ?

```
[Wed, 28 Dec 2016 11:57:45 virt-install 17391] DEBUG (urlfetcher:1169) Regex didn't match, not a ALT Linux distro
[Wed, 28 Dec 2016 11:57:45 virt-install 17391] DEBUG (urlfetcher:196) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.VxW9Li/current/images/MANIFEST
[Wed, 28 Dec 2016 11:57:45 virt-install 17391] DEBUG (urlfetcher:101) Fetching URI: /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.VxW9Li/install/netboot/version.info
[Wed, 28 Dec 2016 11:57:45 virt-install 17391] DEBUG (urlfetcher:112)     Saved file to /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinst-version.info.C0NcW7
Retrieving file version.info...                    |116 B  00:00:00
[Wed, 28 Dec 2016 11:57:45 virt-install 17391] DEBUG (urlfetcher:446) Detected distro name=Ubuntu osvariant=linux
[Wed, 28 Dec 2016 11:57:45 virt-install 17391] DEBUG (urlfetcher:196) local hasFile: Couldn't find /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.VxW9Li/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/i386/linux
[Wed, 28 Dec 2016 11:57:45 virt-install 17391] DEBUG (urlfetcher:243) Cleaning up mount at /var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtinstmnt.VxW9Li
[Wed, 28 Dec 2016 11:57:45 virt-install 17391] DEBUG (cli:295)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 1084, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virt-install", line 1078, in main
start_install(guest, continue_inst, options)
```

Can someone pls suggest?

Answer (score 2):

From debug, it can be see it is indeed looking for `i386`, which is "default arch".

Exact same problem has been tackled in [askubuntu q/a](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809062/error-couldnt-find-hvm-kernel-during-kvm-guest-install-of-ubuntu-server-16-04) and has been [patched](https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/commit/3f15a489cda87f8028828d567848193dd2640a43) to detect architecture from ISO name correctly.

Virt-manager with the patch does not have official release, so one would need to run `virt-manager` from sources or tinker with existing installation by changing and compiling `/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/urlfetcher.py` file.